# Not mandatory bean in Java

Tags: java, spring, config, javabeans

I have the ApplicationConfig.java file which contains 2 beans which are not mandatory.

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:config/service/application.properties")
 public class ApplicationConfig {
  @Bean
  public ServiceOneClient serviceClient(@Value("${client.one.host}") String host)) {
    return new ClientOneImpl(String.format("%s:%d", host, 80));
  }

  @Bean
  public ServiceTwoClient serviceClient(@Value("${client.two.host}") String host)) {
    return new ClientTwoImpl(String.format("%s:%d", host, 80));
  }
}
```

Well the service who uses this jar doesn't have to init both clients. But if we don't init the host for both services then we get error message:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name , Could not resolve placeholder 'client.one.host'

Is there a way to mark bean as not mandatory? or other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) annotation:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config/service/application.properties")
public class ApplicationConfig {
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty("client.one.host")
  public ServiceOneClient serviceClient(@Value("${client.one.host}") String host)) {
    return new ClientOneImpl(String.format("%s:%d", host, 80));
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty("client.two.host")
  public ServiceTwoClient serviceClient(@Value("${client.two.host}") String host)) {
    return new ClientTwoImpl(String.format("%s:%d", host, 80));
  }
}
```

See e.g. [A Custom Auto-Configuration with Spring Boot | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration) for more information about *conditionals* when auto-configuring. Section [3.3. Property Conditions](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration#3-property-conditions) describes the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation.